# Error = 'str' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

Tags: python

Disclaimer: I'm new to Python so this is probably wrong in many ways...

Question: I wish to upload a csv to python, split the data into a test and training set, and then export the test and training sets into two separate csv files. I have the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
    
dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Dividing dataset into label and feature sets
X = dataset.drop('Bankrupt?', axis = 1) # Features
Y = dataset['Bankrupt?'] # Labels

# Normalizing numerical features so that each feature has mean 0 and variance 1
feature_scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = feature_scaler.fit_transform(X)

# Dividing dataset into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split( X_scaled, Y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100)

#Export to csv
X_train = pd.DataFrame.to_csv(r'file path where csv is to be stored\training.csv', index = False)
X_test = pd.DataFrame.to_csv(r'file path where csv is to be stored\test.csv', index = False)
```

But I keep getting the following error: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

Anything I'm doing wrong or any better ways to achieve the same result?

Comment: Please post the stack trace next time, indicating on which line the error originates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_csv` is a method on `DataFrame`, so I think you meant `dataset.to_csv` instead of `pd.DataFrame.to_csv` in the last two lines.

Answer (score 2):

pd.Dataframe is the data frame *class*, not an instance.  `to_csv` is intended to be an instance method, called from an instance.  If you call it as a class method (as you did), its first argument must be a data frame.

Either of these should work:

```
dataset.to_csv(r'file path ...)   # This is the intended use
pd.DataFrame.to_csv(dataset, r'file path ...)   # Harder to read and more prone to error
```